# Excel VBA to vlookup part of a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a Excel VBA macro that looks for "a123Apple873hhh" and knows that I just wanted to look for "Apple".

It's easier to understand on an example:

On sheet1 I have my fixed table array with a name and its code:

```
Column A---Column B
12------ --Banana
20-------- Apple
44-------- Orange
```

On sheet2 I have what I want to look for:

```
Column A----------Column B
.......... -------ds$$Orange1111aaa
.......... -------22Apple999
.......... -------22Watermelon
.......... -------9q9Orange7ab
etc...
```

I want a VBA that looks on sheet2/Column B, finds what name is on sheet1/Column B and give its code on sheet2/Column A.
So, the final result is:

```
Column A------Column B
44 -----------ds$$Orange1111aaa
20 -----------22Apple999
*BLANK* ------22Watermelon
44 -----------9q9Orange7ab
etc...
```

My code don't work because it just find exact results:

```
Sub FindCode()
Const COLUMN As String = "E"
Dim i As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
With ActiveSheet
iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 6 To iLastRow
If .Cells(i, "E") = "" Then
.Cells(i, "A").Value = ""
Else
.Cells(i, "A").Value = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, "E").Value, Range("etc!A:B"), 2, False)
End If
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the values in sheet2 always like `ds$$Orange1111aaa` where the part of the string that you are interested in beginning with an upper case letter in A-Z and consisting of contiguous letters until terminated by a non-alphabetical character? If so, it would be easy to write a VBA function to extract it.

Comment: You have several problems here.  First, you need to find a way to extract the fruit from the column.  Try to do this, and if you have issues ask a problem specifically about that.  Second, your understanding of `VLOOKUP` is not correct.  It will try to find the value in the first column of the range (listed as the second parameter), and return the value in the column number in the third parameter.  So I'd work on that too.  Perhaps by actually using a `VLOOKUP` in a worksheet to see how it works.  The function in VBA replicates the worksheet function.

Comment: On a sidenote, if the values surrounding the fruit are random, it will likely be difficult to parse it out.  You could try doing it in reverse.....loop through each fruit in the lookup checking each cell for the fruit and then pasting the value if it matches.

Comment: You might want to try this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011 (fuzzy lookup add-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim fruitRng As Range, cell As Range, found As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set fruitRng = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
            For Each cell In fruitRng
                Set found = .Find(what:=WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell.Value), lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not found Is Nothing Then
                    firstAddress = found.Address
                    Do
                        found.Offset(, -1).Value = cell.Offset(, -1).Value
                        Set found = .FindNext(found)
                    Loop While found.Address <> firstAddress
                End If
            Next cell
            .Offset(, -1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).ClearContents
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This code is faster than the one on the previous anwser.

Comment: @JoãoVitorDenardiBosa, doesn't the code provided is not the best solution anymore?

Answer (score 4):

### This code isn't very flexible, and has some game breaking limitations, but it *does* do what you're asking.

**I used the exact same data you provided. Sheet1 look like this:**

[image]

**Sheet2 is as follows:**

[image]

**I used this code**

```
Sub SearchProduct()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    Dim fruit As Range: Set fruit = ws1.Range("B2", ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    Dim fruitCode As Range: Set fruitCode = ws2.Range("B2", ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    Dim f As Range, s As Range

    For Each s In fruit
        For Each f In fruitCode
            If InStr(s.Text, f.Text) <> 0 Then
                s.Offset(0, -1).Value = f.Offset(0, -1).Value
                GoTo SkipTheRest
            End If
        Next f
SkipTheRest:
    Next s
End Sub
```

**Which yielded the following result on Sheet2**

[image]

---

Some of the limitations are as follows:

1. If you have something like Green Apple, it won't find the value because of the Space. This can be easily fixed by using `Replace()`.
2. If you have something like Watermelon, and another item as Melon, it's going to give the Melon ID # to both. Some fancier coding (a bit of it actually) would be needed to avoid this.
3. There's a few other issues that may come up depending on the values you're using but they are for the most part small edits to the code. The above two issues (namely 2.) is going to be pretty difficult to avoid..

Comment: Not a bad answer, but the nested loops will prevent it from scaling well. I would at the least invert the order of the loops and break out of the inner loop as soon as you find a match. That would make it 50% faster on average.

Comment: I've never thought to do that yet. I don't think I've dealt with large enough data loops to see much of a delay. I need more experience!

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked on my case, but as John Coleman noted, it toooks 15 seconds to run on my 400 rows. Also thanks for writing the limitations! Really helpful.

Comment: @JoãoVitorDenardiBosa I already inverted them from what they were after john said that.. it's in the right order now... also if it does work for you, can you select it as the answer? thanks

Comment: @JoãoVitorDenardiBosa See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235